# named anchors in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is there a way of generating the equivalent of `<a name="anchor">` in Blade?

*(SO won't let me post such a short question but I've nothing to usefully add to it.)*

Comment: What’s wrong with `<a name="anchor">`? Why do you want to invoke a template engine to write something so simple?

Answer (score 1):

You can [create your own Blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade)

> Blade allows you to define your own custom directives using the directive method. When the Blade compiler encounters the custom directive, it will call the provided callback with the expression that the directive contains.

However in this case I'd recommend you to just use `<a name="anchor">` instead of creating custom Blade directive.